# filter a loop base on specific category

Tags: categories, theme-development, loop

i am going to filter my loop base on the category the problem is that when i am using the following code it display all my post.

```
// Query args
$custom_cat_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'category' => get_cat_ID( 'سیاست' )
);
// Instantiate query
$custom_cat_query = new WP_Query( $custom_cat_args );
// Instantiate loop
if ( $custom_cat_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $custom_cat_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_cat_query->the_post();
    // Normal loop markup here
// Close loop
endwhile; endif;
// Restore $post global
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no valid query argument - `category`, it could be `category_name` or `cat`. So for your query, you can use -

```
$custom_cat_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'cat' => get_cat_ID( 'سیاست' )
);
```

Or

```
$custom_cat_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'category_name' => 'سیاست'
);
```